# Send data from drupal form to Web service Client (REST)

Tags: web-services, drupal-6

I create a simple form. When I put data in all fields of the form and press a submit button, then all data that were completed on the form should be sent to a Web service client (rest).

My question is, how to send all data from my form to web service? Is there a module for that or I have to draw on an API?

Thanks :D

UPDATE:

I created my form that contains 2 fields: "Name" and "Phone" and a submit button. (All in my own module)

Then I show my code that I just did. However, when I see the web service. The shipping data, not shown. I did a debug and uh I realized that when running: "curl_exec ($ch)" returns me FALSE.

```
function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state){    
    $name = $form_state['values']['name'];
    $phone = $form_state['values']['phone'];

    $data = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'phone' => $phone
    );

    $url = 'http://[IP]/event/management/attendee';

    $headers = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');


    $userpasswd = 'user:pass';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpasswd);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

The params,in the web service, are: attendee['name'], attendee['phone']. What is my error?

Answer (score 0):

Sure man try the service module 3 . It's one of drupal great module as usual .
here's the link ( http://drupal.org/node/736522 ) , you can also authenticate user before getting the fields by using two techniques either session authentication or aouth authentication .. you can call your drupal from client application by one of those approach "json,xml-rpc, rest".

1- first the session authentication takes a user name and password and authenticates. Then it takes the user permissions from drupal so you need to authenticate in each step to go through your application that communicate with your drupal. Anonymous users can get what they want according to your permission in drupal.

2- While in Aouth authentication you create a user and add token to him and only the user who had the token communicate with the application according to the permission rule you set to him . In case of anonymous users they can't retrieve or get anything. The communication between drupal and the client within the created used with a certain token.

Feel free to contact me for more support.

Comment: uuhhmm I use Service module when my drupal is a service. But in this case, i want to send data from my drupal to webservice. Ok, I'll update my question, i create own module that using cURL for transfer data. But doesn't work.. :(

Comment: Sorry for my mistake in understanding .

Answer (score 0):

sorry for miss-understanding .

there's two implementation method to do this :

1- You may do a custom module which hooks on the node_api and on submit form get posted data and send it to webservice by this method

```
$json = drupal_http_request('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false');
$decode = json_decode($json->data, TRUE);
```

or by using this module web service client module ( http://drupal.org/project/wsclient ) this is only for drupal 7

2- and this is a guide about this module http://drupal.org/node/1114308 .